# List out of range : I tried to look at the file but conot find where the error lied

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, tags, treetagger

I tried this script with my file which contains approx 16 columns and 5243 lines ,

the first column are respectively the key (just integers 1 to 5243) and the second column is the values which are sentences  (the sentences can be very long up to paragraph )

When i tried with small file it works beut with the true file , it is not working.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs 
import re
import os
import sys, argparse
import subprocess
import pprint
import csv
from itertools import islice
import pickle

try:
    import treetaggerwrapper
    from treetaggerwrapper import TreeTagger, make_tags
    print("import TreeTagger OK")
except:
    print("Import TreeTagger pas Ok")

from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict

#export le lexique de sentiments
pickle_in = open("dict_pickle", "rb")
dico_lexique = pickle.load(pickle_in)


# extraction colonne verbatim
d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='cp1252',) as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        token = line.split(';')
        d[token[0]] = token[1]
#print(d)

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')
d_tag = {}
for key, val in d.items():
    newvalues = tagger.tag_text(val)
    d_tag[key] = newvalues

#print(d_tag)


d_lemma = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d_tag.items():
    for elem in v:
        parts = elem.split('\t')
        d_lemma[k].append(parts[2])

#print(d_lemma) 
print('ok')
```

results

```
import TreeTagger OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CSV_dico.py", line 50, in <module>
    d_lemma[k].append(parts[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
abordables      ADJ     abordable
sur     PRP     sur
le      DET:ART le
marché  NOM     marché
.       SENT    .
Moins   ADV     moins
cher    ADV     cher
...     PUN     ...
25      NUM     @card@
%       SYM     %
de      PRP     de
moins   ADV     moins
...     PUN     ...
C'      NAM     C'
est     VER:pres        être
quand   ADV     quand
-même   ADJ     même
moins   ADV     moins
qualitatif      ADJ     qualitatif
qu'     KON     que
un      DET:ART un
seau    NOM     seau
!       SENT    !
```

Comment: print and check  what is in your variable 'token', obviously is empty

Comment: ... which implies that there is a line with no ';'

Comment: @ncica I print token and it gives each row

Comment: An example of the file would be nice

Comment: can you show how your token looks like

Comment: @ncica  , I solve the problem there were lines which contains ponctuation and were empty  I change in the original files 
but now I want to retrieve the lemma to form the dictionnary and i have some errors   File "CSV_dico.py", line 50, in <module>
    d_lemma[k].append(parts[2])
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an solution but a tip for finding the error:

Try changing this part:

```
# extraction colonne verbatim
d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='cp1252',) as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        token = line.split(';')
        d[token[0]] = token[1]
```

To this:

```
# extraction colonne verbatim
d = {}
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='cp1252',) as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        token = line.split(';')
        try:
            d[token[0]] = token[1]
        except:
            print(line)
```

This should give you the wrong token line and you can check it for erros

Comment: thank you i used your solution to find the error and it is working than  you very much